# DeprecationWarning: Buffer() is deprecated due to security and usability issues

Tags: angular, angular-universal

I downloaded below angular project and followed their instruction to install.

https://snipcart.com/blog/angular-seo-universal-server-side-rendering

`npm install` ... works fine.

`ng serve` .... works fine

`npm run build:ssr` && `npm run serve:ssr` ... this giving an error.

> (node:5644) [DEP0005] DeprecationWarning: Buffer() is deprecated due
>   to security and usability issues. Please use the Buffer.alloc(),
>   Buffer.allocUnsafe(), or Buffer.from() methods instead.

[image]

I am using node version `v10.1.0`

on localhost, it is running though having DeprecationWarning. But the server.js inside dist folder no way running after showing the same error.

Can anyone suggest why I am getting this error and what is the solution?

Comment: anybody able to resolve this issue ?

Answer (score 2):

welcome to Stack Overflow.

I came across [this github issues about yarn](https://github.com/yarnpkg/yarn/issues/5477#issuecomment-412170299) and they talk about the issue (also discuss about Node) and it seems it's something that is fixed but is just waiting for the update.  Therefore it seems you have to wait it out and then be sure to update?  Perhaps try an update with Node now and see if that will fix it but they seem to have fixed and committed the goodness but it's now a waiting game.

*edit can I ask is the app running?  It looks like it from your uploaded photo.  I'll update you if I find anything else but i'd follow the issue form that Repo and see if anything new comes up.

Hope that helps!

Comment: I don't think I understood your question.  Do you mean what's the best way to maximize an Angular6 app for SEO?  And what do you mean by configuring both locally and server side?  Apologies.  Perhaps I'm not fully understanding or aware of what you mean in reference to SEO and Angular6 Apps.