# How to fix DeprecationWarning: Buffer() is deprecated due to security and usability issues

Tags: angular7

I am trying to run angular7 universal application on Window 10 computer, I have used https://angular.io/guide/universal post for setup and I am getting following issue.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KsBvE.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sfb62.png)
And http://localhost:4000/ is not loading at my end.

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [DeprecationWarning: Buffer() is deprecated due to security and usability issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51960591/deprecationwarning-buffer-is-deprecated-due-to-security-and-usability-issues)

Answer (score -1):

Use Buffer.alloc(), Buffer.allocUnsafe() or Buffer.from() methods

Comment: where I have to use Buffer.alloc(), Buffer.allocUnsafe() or Buffer.from()